# Process to transfer Ubuntu partition to another computer

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I am planning the upgrade of my gui-less, headless home server from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04. I'd like to
a) minimize downtime of the live system for the install and configuration
b) do a clean install to remove four years of cruft, and
c) avoid hooking up a monitor/keyboard to the live system (I use ssh to administer it).

My plan is to install and configure 22.04 and all the services on an auxilliary system (different hardware, but with monitor/keyboard), then copy that partition to an empty partition on the primary server. A few config edits and then a reboot will switch over to the newly built system.

I am uncertain about what has to be done once I copy the partition, but before I boot it ("a few config edits" above). I could not find a close use-case match describing the process, though I found some similar ones.

Once I get my 22.04 system in place in its own partition, I will mount that partition in the 18.04 environment and make the needed configuration changes. Things I need to do, as I understand it, are:

- Set hostname to be the same as the 18.04 system (/etc/hostname, anywhere else??)
- Update the uuid(s) in fstab
- GRUB2 config file and components in grub.d on 22.04: what has to be done here?; set the 22.04 partition to be the default boot
- GRUB2 config file edit / activation on 18.04 to add the new partition and set it to be the default boot
- Reboot
- Make GRUB2 on 22.04 take over the boot partition (how to do this??)
- (eventually) remove the 18.04 information from the grub configuration
- (eventually) zero out the 18.04 partition (in preparation for 26.04!)

It's the grub stuff that I'm most uncertain about. I did see the multi-boot spec page that someone with a similar question was referred to, but could not distill it to my needs. Is the sequence that I've laid out right? Any details or gotchas? Specifics welcome!

I'm also concerned about ethernet and drive device names -- if they are not the same, what needs updating ahead of time? Will I know before I can't ssh in?

Finally, will my permissions be ok if I edit files on the mounted 22.04 partition (as root) from the running 18.04 system?

Comment: Hello. Would just like to remind you that 22.04 does not get released till the end of April. No one knows for sure 100 percent what it will do exactly. Features and specs could still change.

Comment: This seems like a very complicated way to "remove four years of cruft" by ... migrating all of it. What sort of data is being migrated that you cannot afford downtime? Databases for a live service? CDN resources? Something else? There may be simpler options available ...

Comment: David: I am planning ahead!

Comment: Matigo, One thing is my pihole, also two media servers. If the rebuild drags on for days (which is might, given my fragmented availability and uncertainty in reconstructing what I have now). Yes, I can reconfigure the dns to bypass the pihole, but I have a spare system and this seemed like a good way to off-line the rebuild. I could not identify a simpler option given my three requirements. I did assume brighter folks than I would have no trouble doing this. But truth be told, it did give me pause that no one else seems to have gone in this direction!

Comment: UEFI or BIOS based systems? Are both UEFI? If you have good backups, you should be able to just install & restore from your backup. If that takes much more than an hour, you backup procedure may need improvement. Some apps may become obsolete or standard that required manual install previously. For example, with 20.04 desktop I did not allow any apps still using python2.

Comment: Oldfred: I do not intend to migrate to a new machine. I intend to build a new 22.04 system and reproduce all the services that I have on the 18.04 system, but using a temporary computer to do so. This will create a drop-in replacement able to be copied to my actual server machine. But it's not quite "drop-in", and hence my question...